# PHP anchor question

Tags: php, jquery

Is there a way to reload a PHP page when a users clicks a PHP link and then have the page jump to a certain spot on the same page using PHP or JQuery like an HTML anchor?

Here is the PHP link below.

```
<a href="../index.php?uid=' . $user_id . '&view=member">' . $user_name . '</a>
```

Comment: I don't think I get your question; you can use anchors without PHP or even Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a hash link, for example:

```
<a href="../index.php?uid='.$user_id.'&view=member#section">'.$user_name.'</a>
```

If in that page you have anything with that ID, say:

```
<div id="section">
```

Then it'd scroll down to there, no jQuery or JavaScript needed...this is normal browser behavior.  [You can read more about it in the HTML4 spec here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.1.1).

As an example, here's a link to the answer you're reading,  see the auto-scroll when you visit it? :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163053#3163061